# MySQL infile ignore header row

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

Trying to get MySQL to ignore a specific row when importing through an INFILE command.  Essentially, it's the "header" row in the CSV file.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\myfile.txt' REPLACE INTO TABLE my_db.my_table;
```

I've looked in to the ignore command, but that's for ignoring duplicate keys.  Is there a way to ignore a specific entry/row in the .txt file?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`IGNORE` has two meanings in a `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement.
The first is replace / ignore when it comes to duplicate key errors.
The second meaning is the one you're looking for. the complete statement is `IGNORE n LINES`

You can't skip a random line but you can skip n lines at the head of your inputfile like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\myfile.txt' REPLACE INTO TABLE my_db.my_table IGNORE 5 LINES;
```

This ignores the first 5 lines, where end of line `EOL` is defaulting to `\n` and can be set to any character using `LINES TERMINATED BY 'CHR'`

Comment: So, if it were `IGNORE 5 LINES` would it ignore the 5th line or would it ignore the first 5 lines?

Comment: this would ignore the first 5 lines, where end of line ( EOF ) is defaulting to "\n" and can be set to any character using `LINES TERMINATED BY 'CHR'`

Answer (score 11):

Add this option to your statement:

```
IGNORE 1 LINES
```

Comment: I like this answer, very straightforward.